# Security implications of userinfo in URL for java.net.HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, security, url, java-security

A string representing a URL is passed to me containing the username and password in the userinfo part of the URL. If I use this URL to open a java.net.HttpURLConnection it does not automatically create the Authorization header, so I am creating the header value and setting it on the connection myself:

```
String host = "https://user:password@example.com";
java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(host);

String userInfo = url.getUserInfo(); // contains user:password
String authHeader = createAuthHeader(userInfo);

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authHeader);

// connection used to open OutputStream, write data, and closed
```

HTTPS is used to protect the Authorization header.

I'm unable to change this string and so unable to separate the userinfo from the remaining URL string.

My question is, are there still security implications for having the userInfo part of java.net.URL set to "user:password", specifically with respect to the server receiving this request or anyone intercepting the request? Or would java.net.HttpURLConnection not send that information at all.

Comment: I have done some rudimentary testing by sending requests using the code in the question to various online request inspectors (requestbin.com, postb.in, and httpbin.org). I was not able to find the user info in any of these inspectors.

Comment: Further tested above request using tcpdump (sudo tcpdump -i any dst XXX.XX.XX.XX -A) to inspect packet content. Tested over both HTTPS and HTTP so I could see the request headers. The user info was not in the packet content.